# Stoi terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion

Tags: c++

```
/* strtok example */
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<list>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  list<string> read;
  char str[] ="g 6 7 v 7 e 0 4 e 11 43 e 25 57 e 3 5 e 4 6 e 5 6";
  char * pch;
  pch = strtok (str," ");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    read.push_back(pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }
  list<string>::iterator i;
  i = read.begin();
  i++;
  int grid_x = stoi(*++i,nullptr,10);
  int grid_y = stoi(*++i,nullptr,10);
  i++;
  int vertices = stoi(*i,nullptr,10);
  return 0;
}
```

I am trying to read in a array of characters into a list of string and then trying to convert the string into integers so that I can make use of these values for further processing. However, I keep running into an error where the compiler tells me

> terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion

I am new to C++ so I am unable to debug.

Is there is an easier way to extract the numbers from the character array?

Comment: _so I am unable to debug the same_ Sorry, this is the right time to learn this urgently. Debugging is an essential skill for C++ development. If you are using VisualStudio, there is a very nice (may be, the best) debugger [First look at the Visual Studio Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2017). On Linux, usually [`gdb`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/) is available which is very powerful. (There might be graphical front-ends about which I've less experience.)

Comment: Re: "Is there an easier way..." -- yes. `std::stringstream ss(str);` Now you can use stream extractors (`ss >> whatever`) to extract input, just as if you had typed it at the command line and used `std::cin`.

Comment: Debugging tip: when operations aren't producing the results you expect, look at the values that are being fed to the operation. `std::cout << *i << '\n;' sprinkled liberally throughout the code will give you a great deal of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
  i++; // points 6
  int grid_x = stoi(*++i,nullptr,10); // skip to 7, read it
  int grid_y = stoi(*++i,nullptr,10); // skip to v and there is no conversion from `v` to int
```

last line in above code crashes, there is no conversion from `v` string to int value, exception was thrown.

While calling `atoi` you should advance `i` after you read it

```
  i = read.begin();
  i++; // advance and i points to 6
  int grid_x = stoi(*i++,nullptr,10); // read 6 and advance
  int grid_y = stoi(*i++,nullptr,10); // read 7 and advance
  int vertices = stoi(*++i,nullptr,10); // advance v and read 7
```

There is difference between `*i++` and `*++i`. In the former case: read value pointed by `i` and advance `i`, in the latter case: advance `i` then read it.

> if there is an easier way to extract the numbers from the character
>   array

it is too broad. Your string has particular format, so you know when you should read int values and `stoi` will do, you need to be careful while iterating over extracted items of string.